# Disable print/copy from a react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, printing

Is there a way to disable functions like copy, printing full page from a react application rendering in browser.

My usecase: I am building a question bank management tool and do not want user to have ability to copy or print complete questions for later reference.

Also is it possible to programatically decide on what will be printed when user tries to print. (Its ok to print title of the questions)

Comment: Even if you build a browser with some security mechanism so that the server only serves the secure browser people could still take photos of their screen.

Comment: It's not really a duplicate as he is asking about react. I had to do somethign similar and I used **react-easy-print** package for that

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot render a page and also prevent a user from seeing it.